# What's the idea behind having internal integration in predictive control?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

According to lots of books about predictive control, they recommend to having internal integration inside the model.

For example if we have a state space model:

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k) \\ y(k) = Cx(k)$$

Then integration will be:

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k)$$
$$y(k+1) = CAx(k) + y(k) + CBu(k)$$

Where $y(k)$ is the output.

When I try to simulate a first order system $Gs) = \frac{1}{3+s}$ with sample time $h = 0.1$, I got this step answer:

[image]
[image]

And adding some integration:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, a pole is placed at $1$. So what's the purpose of having internal integration? Removal of the steady state error?